# extracting a byte from memory by bit address

Tags: c++

I'm dealing with data that has various weird amounts of bits in its values (like 3 bits or 71, anything you can imagine), all tightly serialized together. To extract the data, I figured I'd first create a function that will retrieve a byte by bit address and then I can tie those together for anything longer than 8 bits.

Right now I'm just very confused, heres what I'm working with:

```
unsigned char Data[] = { 0, 255, 2, 255, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
UInt64 BitLen = 64; //test data
UInt64 ByteLen = BitLen % 8 == 0 ? BitLen / 8 : BitLen / 8 + 1;

....

unsigned char GetUChar(UInt64 BitIdx) {
    UInt64 ByteIdx = BitIdx / 8;
    UInt16 Bulk = ByteLen - 1 == ByteIdx ? Data[ByteIdx] : *(UInt16*)&Data[ByteIdx];
    return Bulk >> (8 - (BitIdx - ByteIdx)) % 8;
}
```

The idea is that if the byte containing BitIdx is the last one in the data set, retrieve the value as char, otherwise as UInt16 (which should get that byte and the next one).
Then

BitOffset = BitIdx - ByteIdx * 8

8 - BitOffset = how much padding from the left

and %8 in the end so that if BitIdx is aligned with ByteIdx, then shift amount = 0.

and then I shift it to the right and return the lower order byte.

So to test, I used an online decimal to binary converter to find out that the test data in binary is

00000111 00000110 00000101 00000100 11111111 00000010 11111111 00000000

and I used the function to find a char starting from BitIdx 14, the result was 10111111 while it needs to be 10000001

For a while I thought the bits were going backwards and then the bytes but nothing makes sense anymore. Is there an easier way to extract X amount of bits starting from bit address Y from a byte array?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to multiply `ByteIdx` by eight before subtracting it from `BitIdx`:

```
return Bulk >> ((8 - (BitIdx - 8*ByteIdx)) % 8);
```

Note: computing `ByteLen` can be simplified using a common trick of adding `N-1` before division:

```
UInt64 ByteLen = (BitLen + 7) / 8;
```

Comment: Yes, just noticed but it still doesn't seem to be working right

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you are running on a little endian system (such as Intel) then reading two bytes as a UInt16 *is* going to give your those bytes "backwards".

e.g.

```
char b[] = {1,0};
UInt16 w = *(Uint16*)&b[0];
```

Gives a `w == 1` (`00000000 00000001`) instead of `256` (`00000001 00000000`) as you might expect.

Comment: Well, yes I am (intel + windows). Now everything is upside down in my brain! :/